# AWS Network Load Balancers - SSL/TLS termination & E2E Encryption

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elb, nlb, aws-nlb

I've read a lot of AWS documentation & just wanted to get my knowledge about NLBs & ALBs straight, because I also found out that there are many workarounds for each case scenario.

- **For E2E encryption** (optimize CPU performance) → configure a TCP listener on port 443 (not a TLS listener).
- **For SSL/TLS termination & encryption in-transit** → configure a TLS listener on port 443 & configure the Target group protocol as TLS on port 443:

  - Client → SSL on LB → SSL on backend

1. Is the information mentioned above correct?
2. Is the main goal of doing *SSL/TLS termination & encryption in-transit* to serve clients HTTPS using an NLB? Because there will be less performance / more latency as the ssl handshake will happen by the LB & by the EC2.